# How to factorize the following summation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have the following sum-of-squares function,

\begin{equation}
E(\text{w})=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\{\sum_{j=0}^{M}w_{j}x_{n}^{j}-t_{n}\}^{2}.
\end{equation}

And I want to take its derivative with respect to w. So I perform the following steps:

$E'(\text{w})=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{d}{d\text{w}}(\{\sum_{j=0}^{M}w_{j}x_{n}^{j}-t_{n}\}^{2})=$

$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}2(\sum_{j=0}^{M}w_{j}x_{n}^{j}-t_{n})\frac{d}{d\text{w}}(\sum_{j=0}^{M}w_{j}x_{n}^{j}-t_{n})=$

$=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{j=0}^{M}w_{j}x_{i}^{j}-t_{n}\sum_{j=0}^{M}x_{n}^{j}$

How could the summation $\sum_{j=0}^{M}$ be factored?

Note that $w_{i}$ refers to the ith element of the vector w. Also, a superscript denotes an exponential.

Comment: You have $M+1$ functions $w_0,w_1,\cdots.w_M$, but what is the unscripted function $w$?

Comment: Sorry @JohnWaylandBales, but I do not understand your question. Could you kindly paraphrase it?

Comment: Is $w$ here intended to be a vector, and thus $E'(w)$ represents the gradient with respect to it? Also is the superscript on $x_n^j$ an exponential or an index?

Comment: @eyeballfrog $w_{i}$ is the ith element of the vector w. On the other hand, the superscript refers to an exponential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When taking the gradient, it's better to look at each component of the gradient individually rather than try to do it all at once. You *can* do it that way, but it's annoying and easy to screw up. The $i$th component of the gradient is given by
$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial w_i}  = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial w_i}\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\sum_{i=0}^M w_j x_n^j - t_n\right)^2 = \sum_{n=1}^N\left(\sum_{j=0}^M w_j x_n^j - t_n\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial w_i}\left(\sum_{j=0}^M w_j x_n^j - t_n\right).
$$
To take the derivative of the sum, we use the fact that by definition, the partial derivative with respect to $w_i$ holds all the other $w_j$ constant. Since the derivative of a constant is zero, only the $w_i$ term of the sum comes out nonzero, giving
$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial w_i}  =\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\sum_{j=0}^M w_j x_n^j - t_n\right)x_n^i = \sum_{j=0}^Mw_j\left(\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n^{j+i}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^N x_n^i t_n.
$$
To find the minimum of $E$ (which I assume is the next step), you set each component of the gradient to zero and solve for $w_j$. This results in a system of linear equations that can be written as $Aw = b$, where $A$ is a matrix with $A_{ij} = \sum_{n=1}^N x_n^{j+i}$ and $b$ is a vector with $b_i = \sum_{n=1}^N x_n^i t_n$. $A$ will be invertible provided the data is not a perfect fit to a polynomial of degree less than $M$. This is always the case if $N \le M$, but for $N>M$ it shouldn't be unless your data set is very special.